# XAMPP or me? localhost/hello sends me to Google

Tags: apache, .htaccess, xampp

I'm messing around with my htdocs/.htaccess file.
I have it completely blank right now - no rewrite rules, nothing, and it's saved obviously.

But when I type localhost/hello it redirects me to:
https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=8tCWVPr3KuKq8wewyIDoAg&gws_rd=ssl

Is this an XAMPP quirk? I can't work out why else it's doing this. If I type anything other than 'hello' it doesn't do this.

Comment: Perhaps the browser is trying to search. Try `http://localhost/hello` or `http://127.0.0.1/hello`

Answer (score 0):

Check carefully that you are typing full word and then pressing enter and not selecting from suggestions of chrome.

In attached image you can see that in the suggestion there is two different icons in front of suggestion: one with search icon and another with page icon. Search icon directs to google search page icon opens the page if available.

The same icon also appears in the address bar and works same.

If there is still problem try different browsers.

[image: localhost redirect to google]

Answer (score 0):

Tried Firefox, and I got the correct Error 404. Chrome however, no matter what sends me to google.
In the end I emptied the cache and that's fixed it. So it seems editing the .htaccess also requires cache deletion on Chrome.
Weird.